# Как в Unity сделать проверку на то, переходил ли я с этой сцену на другую?

Tags: unity3d

Есть 1 сцена на ней кнопка, которая переводит меня в другую сцену, как сделать проверку на эту кнопку , чтобы если уже переходил по этой кнопке, то эта сцена уже не загружалась , а загружалась та на которою я перешел в первый раз.

Comment: самый тупой вариант, если сцены всего две, то заведи статическую переменную `short sceneIdx` в которой при клике меняй индекс сцены. `sceneIdx = sceneIdx == 1 ? 0 : 1`....  а дальше загружай сцену с индексом `LoadScene(sceneIdx)` ...... собственно, если сцен больше двух, то условие задачи и не выполнить в принципе

Comment: А если допустим на первую сцену поместить панель с выбором трех сцен, и можно ли сделать вот эту панель активной только при единственном первом входе в игру, в которой он сможет сделать выбор на переход из 3 сцен. А при дальнейшем входе в игру загружалась эта же первая сцена но уже без панели, а только лишь с одной кнопкой которая бы переходила именно на ту сцену которую он выбрал при первом входе в игру?

Comment: Можно. Это называется сохранение. и чтение из сохраненных данных

Comment: Можете на примере чего нибудь объяснить? Или что необходимо задействовать? Буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 2):

Делаешь сцену пустышку, на которой делаешь скрипт, в которой осуществляешь проверку:

```
    string firstScene = "firstScene";
    string nameScene = PlayerPrefs.GetString("SelectedSceneWhenFirstEnterInGame",string.Empty);
    SceneManager.LoadScene( nameScene == string.Empty?firstScene: nameScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

Сохранять лучше всего имя сцены, потому что уследить за именем проще, чем за индексом( добавил сцену и порядок индексов сместился).

На **firstscene** при нажатии на кнопку делаешь:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("SelectedSceneWhenFirstEnterInGame", selectedScene);
SceneManager.LoadScene( selectedScene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

где **selectedScene** имя выбранной сцены.